# why we need to passing props down to children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

i'm getting stuck , there is expenseForm (children) .if you look onSubmit takes an object "expense" why we need at this place .indeed we already dispatch some action .

```
<Expenseform   onSubmit={expense => {
          props.dispatch( AddExpenses (expense));
          props.history.push("/");
        }}
      />
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please could you take a minute to review your question and reword it to be more easily answered.  As it stands, your question is quite vague as to what is wrong and what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`props` are designed in `react` to pass data from parents to children.**

** change in `props` triggers a rerender of the component that the props are passed to, which refreshes your UI

> if you are not passing data from parent to child, you don't need them. It depends on what you want to do with your component.

Comment: It might be also worth mentioning that a change in props triggers a rerender of the component that the props are passed to, which refreshes your UI